# How to show missing index pattern data in EFK

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, td-agent

I have 15 log files which are connecting to some services and saving data. I am uploading the data for these log files in elastic search using `td-agent`. I have created index pattern for each log files in `td-agent-config` file. I have log files with name as:

```
health_sqlservice
health_tcpservice
health_pingservice
```

and so on. So I have also created the name as index pattern. In `elasticsearch`, instead of adding all the 15 index pattern, I have created index pattern as `health_*` so under this index pattern, all the 15 logs data is saved. I can then easily query and create dashboard for the list of services currently running.

But I also want to check the service which is offline. Which means I need to check which are the index pattern data not coming in elasticsearch. I have tried looking for this online but didn't get any results on how to show list of offline index pattern data. Can anyone please give some good suggestions. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Hi, would this be a solution (Field Collapsing, using `log.file` instead of `project_id`) ? It might allow you to display each file's last log entry's timestamp : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-it-possible-to-return-only-the-most-recent-of-each-document/172011/2

Comment: @Imsec Sorry I didnt understand. Can you explain a bit more pls. Also the link you have shared, it shows query and I am not sure how I can create visualization/dashboard based on query results